# How to reach bot service (microsoft bot framework) deployed to azure via fiddler ?

Tags: botframework

I have a bot service in which I created a new get endpoint using the following 
code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("bot/test")]
public async Task TestController() 
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Now I want to hit the endpoint using the fiddler. But my request is not getting authenticated. I am using bot sdk v3. Earlier when I was using bot sdk v1, I was able to make request using fiddler by providing 
`authentication: basic base64(appId:appsecret)`
Any pointers as to How can I make request to v3 bot service?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using the [Bot Framework Emulator](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/tools/bot-framework-emulator/) instead of Fiddler.  It provides a much richer debugging experience.